# Когда после присоединительного союза ОДНАКО запятая, когда после другой союз, не ставится?

Tags: пунктуация, союзы

В [справочнике (пункт 5-4)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140) сказано, что после присоед. союза *однако* запятая ОБЫЧНО (то есть не 'чаще всего, всегда', а именно 'обычно') ставится. Пример: *Однако, если обстоятельства того потребуют, я в стороне стоять не буду*.

Вопрос: когда же тогда после *однако* запятая НЕ ставится? Может, когда после *однако* следует союз двойной?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Трудно уловить какую-либо **закономерность**, так как писатели ставят знак **по своему разумению,** учитывая **структуру** предложения и расстановку ударений.
2. Союз ***ОДНАКО*** трехсложный (в отличие от союзов ***И,  А, НО***), его удобно выделить ударением (это позиция **вводного слова**).  Но в правилах говорится, что в  **начале** предложения у нас находится **присоединительный союз.**
3. А какая здесь разница? Обособляем союз — значит, приравниваем его **к вводному слову**. Нестыковочка! Тогда говорим, что запятая ставится **после союза** (чтобы не огорчать составителей правил и не создавать **прецедента**).

**Примеры из [Нацкорпуса](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CnUiLgosCioKJHByaV9jYXQ60YXRg9C00L7QttC10YHRgtCy0LXQvdC90LDRjxoCCAEqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCIgogCh4KA3JlcRIXChXQvtC00L3QsNC60L4g0LXRgdC70LgwAA==):**

***Однако если** не углубляться в сюжЕт, // нельзя не признать, что волк — красивое животное.*

***ОднАко, / если** вы не прОтив, // мы продолжим этот разговор в саду.*

**Однако если** без дОмыслов, // **то** ясно лишь, что фамилия сложилась именно из прозвища.

***ОднАко, / если** здраво рассуждАть, // **то** вины кораллов в этом нет.*

Comment: Я вас спросил об этом, но без обид, без криков и всего прочего. Ладно, принимаю ваш ответ. Извините, если чем-то обидел.

Comment: Извините и вы, комментарии удаляю.  Желаю удачной работы.

Comment: Sharon, можете пояснить, немного не понимаю вот это: "Обособляем союз — значит, приравниваем его к вводному слову. Нестыковочка! ... (чтобы не огорчать составителей правил и не создавать прецедента)".  И в опушном примере вас не смущает запятая, несмотря на наличие ***то***?

Comment: В Нацкорпусе много примеров с таким оформлением. Меня не смущает, потому что я вижу здесь вводное слово,  отнесенное к подчинительному союзу ЕСЛИ, а не присоединительный союз. Но считать его вводным словом не разрешается. А авторы текстов, возможно, тоже видят, как и я.  Впрочем, вряд задумываются об этом.

Comment: А! В этом нестыковочка? Тогда хорошо.

Comment: Опушный? Кстати, я тут полистала диалектные словари, какие нашла. И вот думаю, есть неплохие словечки. Их можно использовать как сленг, и придумывать ничего не надо.  Для экспрессии и украшательства речи)

Comment: Все удаляем, разборки здесь ни к чему. Я просто не люблю единственно правильные ответы на все случаи жизни, а вы их постоянно ищете. Разная идеология, поэтому такая реакция. «Верно» может быть только здесь и сейчас, то есть для конкретного случая. Розенталь пишет про присоединительные союзы весьма неопределенно: как правило, не обособляется; наличие паузы (ее можно сделать или не сделать); обычно обособляется.  И почему разное отношение к союзам? Это тоже не говорится. Поэтому такие задачи решаются по месту. И вы видите в Нацкорусе  разные авторские решения.

Comment: Я вот сейчас думаю, что союз НО – противительный,  как и ОДНАКО.  У них разная фонетика, но сходное значение. Мы выделяем НО паузой, возможно, на тех же основаниях (приравнивая союз к вводному слову), но реже. И относятся присоединительные союзу к предыдущему тексту, в этом их особенность.