# Нужно ли ставить запятую на стыке «однако когда»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, значение, интонация

Хотела бы узнать: ставится ли на стыке союзов **«однако когда»** запятая?

Например: ***Однако(,) когда […] возникла перед ним на пороге, ему захотелось лишь захлопнуть перед ней дверь.***

Посмотрела в НКРЯ, и там везде пишется по-разному:

> *Однако, когда есть все, обязательно чего-нибудь да не хватает.*
>
> *Мне показалось, что она плачет, однако, когда она снова заговорила, ее голос звучал спокойно.*
>
> *Однако когда я упомянул в разговоре Че Гевару, дядя насторожился.*
>
> *Однако когда мы приблизились к ним и Мила уже протянула руку, чтобы погладить их, они стремительно сорвались с места и исчезли в чаще.*

Хотелось бы узнать, есть ли какое-то правило, по которому можно сориентироваться, ставится ли запятая?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Когда после присоединительного союза ОДНАКО запятая, когда после другой союз, не ставится?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476846/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%8e%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%9e%d0%94%d0%9d%d0%90%d0%9a%d0%9e-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%8e%d0%b7-%d0%bd%d0%b5)

Comment: Такие вопросы  не стоит считать дубликатами.  Даны 4 предложения. Варианты по Розенталю возможны, правило известное. Но надо  в каждом случае обосновать выбор автора.

Comment: @Sharon, не увидела в этом вопросе из-за его формулировки ничего нового по сравнению с предыдущим.

Comment: Тогда нужно его редактировать,чтобы увидеть.  К примеру, добавить следующее: Как объяснить  выбор запятой в приведенных из Нацкорпуса примерах. Попробуйте ответить на этот вопрос, это было бы интересно и познавательно для всех. Мы увидим, как  используется правило  Розенталя на практике. Я пока не отвечаю, потому что мне надоело себя слушать, да и всем тоже, наверное))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Правило известное, это **Розенталь**: после союза **однако** запятая **обычно** ставится.

Но обычно — это **не всегда**, так что решение принимает автор, учитывая **контекст** и грамматическую структуру **самого предложения**. Поэтому предложение нужно приводить полностью, иначе анализировать его **НЕ ИМЕЕТ СМЫСЛА**.

2. **Рассмотрим примеры из Нацкорпуса**.
3. *Как некоторые любят и собирают кукол, так Маруся собирала диваны. Каких только у нее не было...**ОднАко,/ когда** есть все, // обязательно чего-нибудь да не хватает. И Маруся просто страдала, что у нее нет дивана-слона с настоящим длинным хоботом и большими неподдельными ушами.*

Предложение с ***однако*** является **смысловым** центром приведенного **текста**. Важно **подчеркнуть** значимость противопоставления "все есть — чего-то не хватает".

2. *Я сразу же его навестил. Мой дядя казался печальным и тихим. Словно обрел какую-то высшую мудрость. **Однако когда** я упомянул в разговоре Че ГевАру, // дядя насторожИлся. — Авантюрист и гангстер, — сказал я. — Тунеядец и болван! — реагировал дядя.*

Важна структура **малораспространенного** предложения. Два ударения в первой части — это неудобно, союз ***ОДНАКО*** близок к союзу ***НО.***

3. *А на мне и без того достаточно... Ее речь становилась все более сумбурной. Она опустилась на стул и закрыла лицо руками. Мне показалось, что она плачет, **однАко, / когда** она снова заговорИла, ее голос звучал спокойно*

Важно **подчеркнуть противопоставление**: *плачет — голос звучит спокойно.*

4. *— Ребята, они совсем не боятся нас! — Ну, ясно! — подтвердил я. — Остров необитаемый, и они никогда не видели людей.
   **Однако когда** мы приблизились к ним и Мила уже протянула руку**, чтобы погладить их, // они стремительно сорвались с места и исчезли в чАще*.

Здесь **два придаточных** связаны союзом ***И***, так что обособлять ***однако*** неудобно.

**ВЫВОД**

Таким образом, запятая ставится в следующих случаях:

(1) Если автор хочет подчеркнуть значение  союза ***однако.***

```
**ОДНАКО. I. союз**. I. Употр. для присоединения 
 предложений или отдельных членов предложения **со 
 значением противопоставления, несоответствия** 
 предшествующему или **ограничения** 
 предшествующего.
```

(2) Если структура предложения позволяет обособить союз ***однако.***

Answer (score 5):

Из [правила](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140) Розенталя (пункт 5):

> **4)** после союза *однако* запятая обычно ставится: ***Однако, если** обстоятельства того потребуют, я в стороне стоять не буду.*
> **Примечание.**  <...>
> **3)** перед придаточной частью запятая ставится в зависимости от значения присоединительного союза и наличия/отсутствия паузы при чтении.

**Ответ:**
*Однако когда […] возникла перед ним на пороге, ему захотелось лишь захлопнуть перед ней дверь.*

Контекста нет (и приходится фантазировать на счет имени или даже словосочетания), но ***однако*** больше тяготеет ко всему предложению, чем просит сближения с вводным словом. Паузу делать не хочется, "главное" ударение переносится на конец первой части или на это *[…]*. Да и по смыслу, без придаточного, не вяжется: *Однако ему захотелось лишь захлопнуть перед ней дверь*.

Все другие предложения, согласно примечанию, могут принять оба варианта. Авторы выбрали один из них по своему замыслу.
В "своем" контексте мы можем сместить ударение, и тогда, например, напишем:
*Кажется, всё **Е**сть. Однако когда есть вс**Ё**, обязательно чего-нибудь да не хватает.*